# Change image to original size on hover

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

Some help needed here.

I have an image control in my aspx page :

```
<dx:ASPxImage ID="ImgSeatPlan" runat="server" ShowLoadingImage="true" CssClass="thumbnail"></dx:ASPxImage>
```

The css class :

```
 .thumbnail {
            width:50px;
            height: 50px;
        }
```

I would like on hover of the image to zoom it to its original size not just scaling it because each image has its own size and when scaling it, lets say for example by 10, then small images are great to see but bigger ones not so great. Also it just scales the 50px by 50px size of the thumbnail and not the original size. 
I am using c# in the code behind.

Any ideas???
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
.thumbnail:hover {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Sorry It does not work. If I add this to my css then the page loads with the image in the original size and not in thumbnail..

Comment: you probably missed :hover, this code only works when hovering

Comment: No. I did not miss it. It does not work. Thank you for trying though.